# How to use http Web Request to Send data to API?

Tags: c#, android, api, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
var update = new update();
update.name = "Test Name";

//Serialize
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(update);


WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("api.example.com/profiles/1");
request.ContentType = "text/json";
request.Method = "PATCH";
```

I have got that match going but from there i am not sure what to do any help is great.

Comment: I would use `HttpClient` instead. One example could be found in here: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PuppyKittyOverflow/blob/master/PuppyKittyOverflow.Portable/OverflowHelper.cs

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole solution for your case:

```
var update = new update();
update.name = "Test Name";
    
var httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create ("api.example.com/profiles/1") as HttpWebRequest;


httpWebRequest.Method = "PATCH";
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
httpWebRequest.Timeout = 5000;

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter (httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream ())) {
    streamWriter.Write (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(update));
}

using (WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse ()) {
    streamReader = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream ());
    var objectResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<your_object> (streamReader.ReadToEnd ());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a HttpURLConnection like this to send name="test name"

```
    String urlParameters = "name="+URLEncoder.encode("test name", "UTF-8");
    URL obj = new URL("api.example.com/profiles/1");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // add request header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```